# Como puedo extraer datos(elementos) de un archivo .CSV en la librería de Pandas en Python?

Tags: python, pandas

La pregunta esta basada en DataFrame(bidimencional) de Pandas/Python, donde tengo un archivo .CSV, con varias filas y columnas.

Necesito obtener un listado de países(Country_Region), dónde NO haya casos de pacientes recuperados(Recovered).

Columnas necesarias "Country_Region y Recovered".

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

df_covid0101 = pd.read_csv("COVID_01-01-2021.csv")

df_covid0101.set_index("Country_Region",inplace=True)

df_covid0101.drop(["FIPS", "Admin2", "Province_State", "Last_Update", "Combined_Key", "Incident_Rate",
                   "Case_Fatality_Ratio","Lat", "Long_", "Confirmed", "Deaths", "Active"], axis="columns", inplace=True)

df_covid0101[df_covid0101["Recovered"] < 1]


-------------------------

                Recovered
Country_Region  
Serbia                0.0
Kiribati              0.0
```

Comment: Qué has hecho hasta ahora? Puedes poner tu código para ver qué problema te estás encontrando?

Comment: Usa [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), eso te devolverá un [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) con los datos del csv. El resto es aprender a interactuar con un dataframe resultante. Luego de aplicar lo que te dije, si te encuentras con un problema especifico, edita esta pregunta y profundisa sobre ese error.

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema. Tal cual tienes planteada la pregunta veo que el dataframe resultante tiene como índices los datos que necesitas.

Comment: @CésarGonzález ,  Pero consultando la tabla, tiene 3682 filas, teniendo más que dos con "Recovered" en 0.0, o sea hay mas paises con pacientes NO recuperados. Lo que no enteindo es eso.

Comment: Has confirmado que el `dtype` de "Recovered" es numérico?

Comment: @CésarGonzález, sí es del tipo float64 ;    Recovered    110535.870588
dtype: float64

Comment: Puedes adjuntar una muestra del csv? En principio no veo que estés haciendo nada mal

Comment: @CésarGonzález, como lo hago ?

Comment: Con head() y to_markdown() por ejemplo y lo pegas en la pregunta: `print(df_covid0101.head(20).to_markdown())`

Comment: @CésarGonzález, en verdad el dataset (DataFrame), tiene 3681 filas, con 13 columnas, entonces en la series (columnas), tendria que extraer un dato concreto de valores Non recuperados, o sea " 0 ".

Comment: @RicardoMCosta Creo que me explique mal con mi comentario anterior. Deberías poner el resultado de esa sentencia, que te genera una tabla en formato markdown para pegarla directamente en tu pregunta